# C: Let the user fill a char array one character by one. Then print it

Tags: c, arrays

I wanna write a program that translates a message entered by the user into B1FF-speak. However, the program seems to crash here:

```
#define MAX_LEN 80

char message[MAX_LEN];

printf("Enter a message: ");
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN - 1; i++)
    scanf("%c", message[i]);

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN - 1; i++)
    printf("%c", message[i]);
```

Where is the mistake? I can't seem to find it.
I wanna understand why this specific piece of code crashes my program.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `MAX_LEN`?

Comment: You're missing an ampersand here: `scanf("%c", message[i]);`. And don't even think of using `gets`. Use `fgets` instead

Comment: I thought using ampersand with character arrays is wrong, since the first element of a char array acts as a pointer to the whole array? Or I am getting something wrong?

Comment: @Shuster You're mixing up stuff. The _name of an array_ gets converted to a pointer to its first element. Basically, don't use the ampersand when scanning in strings like: `scanf("%s", message);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are expected to pass a pointer to *scanf*. 
Normally you pass an array (which is a pointer), or a char-pointer (string). What you are doing is passing the char itself. The method has no possibility to write something into the char, because it is copied before the function call.

What happens then is that the method interprets the uninitialized char as an address and tries to write to a random location which most likely fails.

Simply pass the address of the char:

```
char message[MAX_LEN];
printf("Enter a message: ");
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN - 1; i++)
    scanf("%c", &message[i]);

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN - 1; i++)
    printf("%c", message[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an ampersand in the scanf statement.

```
scanf("%c", &message[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the address to scanf:

```
scanf("%c", &message[i]);
```